# History of the American Southwest

Tags: native-americans, precolumbian-era

I'm planning a road trip through the Southwest U.S., stopping at a lot of national parks and historical sites (click for details):

[image]

I'd like to listen to audio books while driving, about the history of the region -- both geological and anthropological. There are a lot of Navajo, Apacha and Hopi sites on the route, a lot of old Pueblo ruins, etc., so I'd like to know more about Native American history, from pre-Columbian times (if possible) up to modern days. I'd also like to learn about the geological history and structures in the region, e.g. the Moenkopi formation, the different strata, when they were laid down, all of that.

Audio books would be preferable -- but, really, any books will do, for bedtime reading between day trips.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Requests for references are out of scope for H:SE. We have been looking for a test case to change that policy, but this question is, IMHO, too broad. It asks about history and geology and ecology for multiple nations and multiple times.

Comment: I think this is a great question.  Reference guide questions should be within the scope for this board.  IMHO, because history, as studied, is not solely fact dependent, relies on other areas of study, including archeology, sociology, economics, political science, etc., we cannot restrict questions in the way we do now.  Also, history should be lived -- visiting battlefields, archeology sites, etc.  Finding them is never easy, though.

Comment: I am leaning toward keeping this question as an excellent general overview of the American South-West. We can concentrate on just the historical aspects of the question of course. but just 4 states of the contiguous 48 seems localized enough for me.

Comment: With all of those stops, this is far too broad a question. Done right, this should take you at least a month. My advice: Don't listen to audio books. Instead, sit back, pay attention to your driving, stop and take some hikes, and enjoy the beautiful scenery.

Comment: I'm actually planning for around 2-3 months, through the winter (when the temperatures will be bearable and some of the higher elevations, like Bryce Canyon, will have snow.) But I'd really like some books to help give me context for what I'll be seeing. I don't really know anything about Native American history, at all, but these tribes lived and fought in these regions and had their own forms of government, and now there's just ruins and reservations. And the rock formations out there, the layers of color, that has to be a story in itself.